# Reading in a file without punctuation

Tags: java, string, io

I'm reading in a file line by line, then analyzing each word.  I'm then printing words to a new file using PrintWriter.  If the word has punctuation, I need to read in the word without the punctuation since I'm writing the punctuation straight to the output file.  If the character is in the middle of the word, I need to split it into two words.

Examples:

- **let's** should be two words, "let" and "s"
- **your,** should just be "your"

I can't think of anything besides checking word.contains() for each type of punctuation and then splitting it up.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`\p{Punct}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which is one of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``, along with `\s` which is a whitespace `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`:

```
line.split("[\\s\\p{Punct}]+");
```

For example:

```
"let's. your!".split("[\\s\\p{Punct}]+");
> ["let", "s", "your"]
```

Comment: @Aaron Hiller in case you don't know it, split() is a method on java.lang.string; you can use the logic in this answer on a line read from your file, and it results in an array of the substrings that were delimited by the characters represented by the suggested argument to split.